# Not able to login to Azure from eclipse

Tags: java, azure, eclipse-plugin

I am under corporate firewall hence got the eclipse neon downloaded with the Azure plugin from the concerned team. Now when trying to log-in to Azure account from eclipse it says

> `"Sign In Error"` and in error details it says `"login.microsoftonline.com"`.

Can anyone help if there is some Issues with proxy or anything in eclipse?
I am able to login to `portal.azure.com` using the same credentials but not from eclipse. Please help.

Comment: Steps followed from  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-sign-in-instructions

Comment: What happens when you execute _Help > Check for Updates_? Eclipse proxy preferences: _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections_.

Comment: Would you please offer a specific screenshot of the error for me to help you solve the login issue?

Comment: It was because of proxy Issues and once the Proxy Issues were set, It started working fine. Adding the proxy details to the browser added the details in the Network connections mentioned by you @howlger. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @karthik Great. I added the answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse a proxy can be set/configured in ***Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections***.